# Pytorch Lightning 2 accuracy collapses

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, floating-accuracy, pytorch-lightning

I am trying to use Lightning PyTorch for the first time, however in testing I am experiencing some strange problems.
I have reported the loss and accuracy trend during the training, however, when I test the network at the end of the training the accuracy collapses under 70% in both the test set, validation set and also in the training set.

```
[train loss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1UkC.png)
[accuracy in training](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0ocG.png)
[validation loss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KuS9J.png)
[accuracy in validation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7fYD.png)
```

To load the weights I used:

`MyLightningModule.load_from_checkpoint("/path/to/checkpoint.ckpt")`

I have tried repeating the workouts several times and loading different checkpoints, but no luck.
Has anyone experienced similar problems or have a solution?

Thanks in advance for anyhelp